# React: avoid child component rerender on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a React app where a graph component fetches and displays data using props passed on from the parent component. The problem is that the parent does some data fetching as well, and updating the parent state (although not affecting the child props) seems to rerender the child thus initiating a duplicate data fetch in the child.

See https://jsfiddle.net/ctombaugh/cgzn7wst/10/ and below for code.

```
function App(props) {
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState(2019);
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert("App is fetching some lists");
    setList(["a", "b", "c"]);
  }, [setList]);
  function handleYearChange(e) {
    setYear(e.target.value);
  }
  return (<div>
    <YearSelector value={year} onChange={handleYearChange}></YearSelector>
    <Plot year={year}></Plot>
  </div>);
}

function YearSelector(props) {
  return <select value={props.value} onChange={e => props.onChange(e)} >
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
}

function Plot(props) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert("Plot is fetching data for " + props.year);
    setData([1, 2, 3]);
  }, [props]);
  return <div>I'm a plot</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Check out [memoization](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever the component is rerendered a new `props` object is generated, so using `props` as a dependency to `useEffect` doesn't really help.

If the side effect of should only be fired if the `year` changes, use just the `year` as a dependency:

```
function Plot({ year }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert("Plot is fetching data for " + year);
    setData([1, 2, 3]);
  }, [year]);
  return <div>I'm a plot</div>;
}
```

Comment: I missed the `props` as a dependency.. That's a much simpler solution than using `memo`.

Comment: Thanks! One additional question: adding the individual props properties as dependencies gives me a `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` warning. Anything I should worry about?

Comment: You're welcome. Remove the props from alert. See updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `React.memo` which is equivalent to PureComponent, but it only compares props. (You can also add a second argument to specify a custom comparison function that takes the old and new props. **If it returns true, the update is skipped**.)

```
const Button = React.memo((props) => {
  // your component
});
```

for more info https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate